# Call by reference in C++

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference

What is actually passed in call by reference to a function?

```
void foo(int &a,int &b)
```

when I write

```
foo(p,q)
```

what is actually passed to the function. Is it the address of p and q?

Comment: I'm assuming you know the programtic difference between a reference and pointer, right?  Are you asking what it actually gets compiled to?

Comment: @Peter In that case, why not simply look at the emitted code?

Comment: How do I do that. I am using a gcc compiler.

Comment: gcc -S will give you asm code to look at

Comment: @Peter The easiest way to examine the code is to run it in a debugger, such as gdb, or if you want a graphical interface Insight or DDD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's actually passed to the function is a reference. The named parameter `b` becomes a synonym for the argument object `q`.

How the compiler probably implements this that the caller places the address of `q` on the stack or in a register before calling, and the callee uses that value to effect all accesses to `b`. But it could be misleading to describe that as "actually passing" a pointer, because parameter passing is a concept at the level of the C++ language, and at that level it is not the same concept as passing a pointer. For instance, when you pass a pointer you can pass a null pointer, but when you pass a reference you cannot (validly). So it'd be wrong to say they're same thing.

That said, the person implementing the compiler might describe it as "actually passing a pointer", and you know what they mean. For comparison, if `char` variables occupy 4-byte stack slots in the calling convention, they might say that the compiler is "actually passing an int". So it depends what "actually" is supposed to mean.

Comment: *"it depends what "actually" is supposed to mean"* ... Politician?

Answer (score 3):

The other answers mention the semantic difference between a reference and a pointer.

In practice, every single compiler I've ever worked with implements them the same way -- passing a reference is really passing a pointer at the assembly level. This isn't specified in any standard, it's just the case in practice everywhere.

The question's come up on SO before: [What's the low-level difference between a pointer an a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640355/whats-the-low-level-difference-between-a-pointer-an-a-reference/1640362#1640362)

Answer (score 2):

It really gets passed a reference type - it's sort of like the address, but not quite.  The actual address would be a pointer.  References are less powerful than pointers, but are arguably safer.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)#Relationship_to_pointers) has a good description of the differences between pointers and references.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a reference, which is not a pointer, and not an address -- but it is similar.

What "exactly" a reference is, isn't set in stone. The standard does not dictate the mechanisms for dealing with reference -- just the consequences of using them. *Usually*, they will be implemented as pointers.

Example:

```
int foo(int& a, int& b) { a = b; }

// Usage
int x, y;
foo(x, y);
```

This might generate the same machine code as:

```
int foo(int* a, int* b) { *a = *b; }

// Usage
int x, y;
foo(&x, &y);
```

But there's no guarantee of that, and the two are NOT equivalent (although they provide similar functionality).

When you take the address of a reference, you get the same address as the object that it is referring to. Example:

```
void foo(int& x) { std::cout << &x << std::endl; }

int y;
std::cout << &y << std::endl;
foo(); // This will print the same as above.
```

Answer (score 0):

The way pass by reference works is defined by your compiler. In any event, they are passed as `int&` which is an actual type in C++. Try this:

```
int x = 10;
int& y = x;
x = 100;
```

What do you think is the value of y? References are not quite pointers but aliases to a variable. The same mechanism that your compiler applies to `int&` is used for pass by reference parameters.

Given the following program:

```
void byRef(int& x)
{
    return;
}

void byVal(int x)
{
    return;
}

void byPtr(int * x)
{
    return;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    int x = 0;
    byRef(x);
    byVal(x);
    byPtr(&x);

    return 0;
}
```

The MSVC90 Assembly generated for the `byRef` and for `byPtr` calls  are exactly the same which is:

```
lea eax, [x]
push eax
call byRef ;or byPtr
add esp, 4
```