# Passing arguments by reference and address

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass objects to functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c)

When should I be passing arguments by reference and when passed by address?

I mean Except the case of pass by const reference, is there any difference between the two.

Comment: check this answer at yahoo answers [http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=1006051001452](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=1006051001452)

Comment: (more than) possible duplicate: [C++ Objects: When should I use pointer or reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288030/c-objects-when-should-i-use-pointer-or-reference/4288087#4288087)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally pass by pointer (address) when the pointer may be null, and pass by reference when it can't be null.

There are plenty of other considerations (const/non-const, smart/weak pointers etc) but I think this is a good guideline and answers your question well.